# Parse.com - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: parse-platform, x86-64

I've updated my project to use the new Parse Framework(1.6.2) and the log shows an problem with the architecture x86_64.
I'm using Standart Arch(armv7,arm64) and the FacebookSDK (w/ -ObjC flag).
Anyone knows how to solve that?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPush.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPinningEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCloud.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTwitterAuthenticationProvider.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObjectEncodingStrategy.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFAnonymousAuthenticationProvider.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Bolts.framework` in your project.